# Inserts locking mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

We currently are seeing record locks during insert after we upgraded mysql from 5.6 to 5.7.  I have disabled the deadlock detection and logging everything but still can't determine why the locks are happening.  It looks like a concurrency issue but this wasn't a problem before 5.7.

How to troubleshoot it better? What is the most likely cause?

Comment: Did you run mysql_upgrade command after the upgrade, 

Can you post any log to see the response?

Comment: Maybe 5.7 is running faster, hence getting more locks?  Let's see the transaction(s) and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Maybe something simple like adding a composite index will uncork the problem (on both versions).

Comment: this issue is only on the new version.  The application is using connection pooling which sounds like the connections are sleeping when not being used.  I kill the offending blocking connection (sleep) and everything flows.   I can send snapshots of innotop if that helps or any log, which log would be helpful.